# Html picture in table, align vertically

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a table with image with html: http://prntscr.com/aixqcj

But the picture leads to a large space at the bottom of the image (padding is 9px, the space is not padding) and that causes a large amount of space on top of the text in the right column: http://prntscr.com/aiy8tg

Eventually I would like the image to align vertically in the column (I saw a lot of posts about vertical alignment but didn't find the solution yet).

Could you help?

Comment: This is my code: http://prntscr.com/aiybqy

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: Can you attach a plain-text code? Screenshots are not useful for us.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `valign="top"` on the `td`.

If you are using HTML5, you will have to use the CSS `vertical-align` property: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_valign.asp